# Java/Swing: Obtain Window/JFrame from inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, swingutilities

How can I get the JFrame in which a JPanel is living?

My current solution is to ask the panel for it's parent (and so on) until I find a Window:

```
Container parent = this; // this is a JPanel
do {
    parent = parent.getParent();
} while (!(parent instanceof Window) && parent != null);
if (parent != null) {
    // found a parent Window
}
```

Is there a more elegant way, a method in the Standard Library may be?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You could use `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(...)`  method that will return a Window that you could cast to your top level type.

```
JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
```

Comment: That worked. You know much that is hidden, O Hovercraft Full Of Eels.

Answer (score 45):

There are 2 direct, different methods for this in `SwingUtilities` which provide the same functionality (as noted in their Javadoc). They return `java.awt.Window` but if you added your panel to a `JFrame`, you can safely cast it to `JFrame`.

**The 2 direct and most simple ways:**

```
JFrame f1 = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(comp);
JFrame f2 = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
```

**For completeness some other ways:**

```
JFrame f3 = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JFrame.class, comp);
JFrame f4 = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getRoot(comp);
JFrame f5 = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getRootPane(comp).getParent();
```

Answer (score 30):

```
JFrame frame = (JFrame)SwingUtilities.getRoot(x);
```

Comment: Javadoc states that this might be an `Applet` (not `Window` or `Frame`).

Answer (score 6):

As other commentators already mentioned it is not generally valid to simply cast to `JFrame`. That does work in most special cases, but I think the only correct answer is `f3` by icza in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25137298/1184842

```
JFrame f3 = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JFrame.class, comp);
```

because this is a valid and safe cast and nearly as simple as all other answers.