# Change a JPanel to another on a JFrame. How?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I have a JPanel (panelOne) on a JFrame (frame). On the panelOne I have two buttons and I like to, If I pushing one button the JPanel will change to another. But how? I can't access the frame from panelOne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the whole tree of components from a Component.

See [Java/Swing: Obtain Window/JFrame from inside a JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650874/java-swing-obtain-window-jframe-from-inside-a-jpanel) to get the top most ancestor.
Also have a look at the Component javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html

Comment: Thanks, I got the Frame. But how can I change the JPanel?

Comment: Have a look at the javadoc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane(java.awt.Container)